# Django: how to read nested url regex

Tags: python, regex, django, url, dispatcher

I have this in the main urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^([\w-]+)/foo/', include('foo.urls')),
)
```

and this in foo.urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url('([\w-]+)/$', FooList.as_view()),
)
```

foo.views.py

```
class FooList(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        print self.args[0]
        return Foo.objects.all()
```

When I go to

```
http://localhost:8000/arg1/foo/arg2
```

I only have 'arg2' in self.args in the FooList get_queryset function. How can I read 'arg1' from this fun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs, it looks like this should work as expected when you use named groups (which end up being `kwargs` instead of `args`): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#captured-parameters

Since that's expected behavior for named groups, it seems sort of odd to me (and clearly to you, since you posted this question) that it's not working for non-named groups. Can't say I've tried either, though. Hope the docs link helps.